# K-means clustering benchmarks

Tags: algorithms, global-optimization

What benchmarks do you use for evaluating clustering algorithms, especially for evaluating the performance of K-means vs. another algorithm?

I am especially interested in looking at the correctness of results, meaning that I am looking for clustering problems that have a pretty good chance of K-means failing to find the optimum clustering.

I should also say that I am also looking for problems in a $n$-dimensional isotropic Euclidean space.

I have found some discussions in published literature, but I wanted to hear about as many perspectives as possible. If you had an algorithm and you wanted to compare it to K-means in terms of its ability to avoid local minima, you would need to test it with a reasonable probability that K-means would do just that, get stuck in a local minima. What kind of a test case would you suggest to give that reasonable probability?

Comment: This post ends mid-sentence.

Comment: I have found some discussions in published literature, but I wanted to hear about as many perspectives as possible.

If you had an algorithm and you wanted to compare it to K-Means in terms of its ability to avoid local minima, you would need to test it with a reasonable probability that K-Means would do just that, get stuck in a local minima.  What kind of a test case would you suggest to give that reasonable probability?

Comment: This question may get closed - it has 4 out of 5 votes at the time of this comment.  The underlying reason, I think, is that it is more of an empirical question than a mathematical one: this forum is about mathematical research, and the goal of mathematical research is to prove interesting theorems rather than hit empirical benchmarks.  I would recommend either posting your question at the stats or datascience stackexchange sites instead.  There might be a formulation of the question which belongs to pure probability theory - that might be appropriate for this forum.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one source:

> P. Fränti and S. Sieranoja.
> $K$-means properties on six clustering benchmark datasets.
> *Applied Intelligence*, 48 (12), 4743-4759, December 2018.
> [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10489-018-1238-7).
> [Web link](http://cs.joensuu.fi/sipu/datasets/).

---

[image]

---